# JFrame doesn't run when inside a .jar file

Tags: java, swing

Next semester I will be studying the book *Introduction to Graphical User Interfaces with Java Swing by Paul Fischer* at my university. In the beginning of the book, he shows how to create a JFrame. I made two files, FrameEx.java and test.java for testing.

By running test.java, the JFrame (window) appeared on screen as desired. This is the code I used.

FrameEx.java:

```
package FrameEx;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FrameEx extends JFrame {

  public FrameEx() {
    this.setSize(256, 128);
    this.setLocation(256, 128);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("Test");
    this.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

test.java:

```
package FrameEx;

public class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    FrameEx window = new FrameEx();

  }
}
```

but when I created the FrameEx.mf file containing:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: test
```

and went to command prompt and did:

```
jar cmf FrameEx.mf FrameEx.jar FrameEx.class test.class
```

The .jar file got created but when I run it nothing happens, no JFrame on screen. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Does your console indicate any exceptions or errors?

Comment: Yeah, I get: Warning: The local variable window is never read

Answer (score 3):

The main-class must be the fully qualified name of the class. This means you should use `FrameEx.test` instead of simply `test`.

[Application Entry Points Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

Comment: But when I do

    public class FrameEx.test {
      public static void main(String[] args) {

I get: Error: Syntax error on token "class", @ expected

Comment: crownjewel82 is suggesting you change the name of the class in the manifest file

Comment: okay, so I tried changing it to FrameEx.test instead of test. It still doesnt' work. Is my file directory maybe wrong? I'm inside the folder FrameEx and there are my FrameEx.java test.java and the FrameEx.mf

Comment: Apparently, I'm getting the "Error: Could not find or load main class FrameEx.test"

Comment: Did you put test.java or test.class into the jar? You can also explode the jar using WinZip or a similar program to see the exact directory structure inside of the jar. It should have the same folder structure as your development directory.

Comment: I added only the .class files. By using jar tf FrameEx.jar I see that my file structure inside is like this:
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
FrameEx.class
test.class

where the manifest holds:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: FrameEx.test

and an empty line below the text. Still doesn't work